# Lightning web component not rendering correctly from quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, quickaction

I have created a lightning web component that displays information from a grand-parent object, parent object and child object. I have created a quick action on the parent object with lightning web component in the development sandbox. The development sandbox is on Summer 21 release and everything is working fine. When I push my changes from Development sandbox to testing sandbox (which did not hit Summer 21 yet), I am getting an error message saying "Lightning component quick actions are not enabled for your organization". I did some google search and based on what I found, I have created a quick action with a new lightning component and embedded my lightning web component in it.

When I add the quick action to the parent object page layout and click on it, it does not display the object details. In the development sandbox where the lightning action is created based off of the lightning web component, it is working fine.

I tried passing the $recordId parameter to the LWC component (which I don't think it is necessary as LWC has access to the recordId variable already on a record page) from the Aura Component for the quick action, but the results were same. Just the canvas is with the lightning-card is popping up with out any details.

UPDATE: I have got this to work by adding force:hasRecordId in the lightning component.

The LWC window is now showing the data, however the modal window has two scroll bars when viewed from a laptop. When I view it on my 27" iMac, the scroll bar is only available on the lightning-card component. When I view on my 15.6" laptop, the lightning-card has a scrollbar and the modal window has another scrollbar. How do I get rid of the scrollbar from the modal window?

Below is the screenshot for reference. I had to cut some data.

[image]

Comment: @manjit5190 They are not empty spaces. In the LWC's lightning card, I have the company logos at the top right and bottom right of the canvas. I just need the outer scrollbar to disappear which is part of the modal window of the lightning component. The inner scrollbar is part of lightning-card and it needs to have the scrollbar as the length of the table depends on the number of records fetched from Slaesforce.

Answer (score 0):

The Create a Lightning Web Component Action was in [pilot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_action.htm&type=5&release=230) in Spring 21 and was made GA in recent release - Summer 21. You need to be enrolled in pilot on the org on previous release OR wait till **Jun 12** for you org to get upgraded.

**Update**

You have too much empty space on your component. The scroll bars depend on screen size and resolution. You may want to remove some padding and margins (like the one on the top and between table cell border text) and give columns width based on data size you are expecting e.g. the second column seems to have more data than first and fourth.

Comment: I know that, however due to our business decision, we wanted to keep our testing sandbox and production at the same release. So, Summer 21 will hit our testing sandbox only on Jun 12, 2021. I have got this to work. However, I have a different question and hence edited my original post. Please help.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Updated the answer above